# What is tax form SA2002, in the UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I am trying to rent a place in London. After providing so many forms the realtor is now asking for SA2002. I have tried searching for this but cannot find out what it is. The realtor has the attitude that I should know. I have been living in the USA for the past 20 years. This year is the first time I filed a tax return since, forever. So, What is the form SA2002?

Comment: There isn't any SA2002 form. Get it clarified from the realtor. Most realtors are fresh out of colleges(and talk smooth) and know nothing about tax matters. Ask him(her) to confirm properly. Their job is to ask for proper documents, which exist, not any forms they decide for themselves. `This year is the first time I filed a tax return since, forever` In UK ?

Comment: Could you clarify: are you trying to find a place to live? If so, by "realtor", do you mean "letting agent"? If so, have they said why they need tax information from you, e.g. as proof of income?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [SA 200](http://search2.hmrc.gov.uk/kb5/hmrc/forms/view.page?record=SCleiU-LYEs)